# Why does re.Match object return an end index higher than expected?

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice, python-re

I'm trying to understand regular expression operations, string slicing, and strings in Python.

String slicing using .start() and .end() results in the expected substring, and if I go for a single character from a string using .start() the resulting character is as expected, but if I go for a single character from a string using the .end() index, it doesn't result in the expected character.

I understand that lists (including strings) begin with element zero, but why are exceptions to this rule the stop index of a string slice and the re Match .end() index?

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search("bake","123bake456")
>>> m
<re.Match object; span=(3, 7), match='bake'>
>>> m.span()
(3, 7)
>>> m.start()
3
>>> m.end()
7
>>> "123bake456"[m.start():m.end()]
'bake'
>>> "123bake456"[m.start()]
'b'
>>> "123bake456"[m.end()]
'4'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: In the answer they state "a[start:stop]  # items start through stop-1". Thinking of "stop-1" is difficult. I prefer to think in absolutes when it comes to programming. I believe chemicalwill answered it with "goes up to" but doesn't include the end index* which is definitely in terms of absolutes. Thank you for answering nonetheless!

Comment: Woodford! The 4th answer down which starts "The answers above don't discuss slice assignment" explains what I needed! Slice assignment vs index assignment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slice goes *up to* the ending index but *does not include* it. i.e. a `span` of `(3, 7)` includes index `6`, but not `7`. Similar to how `range(1,100)` would go 1-99 but not include 100.